# How are statistics recorded in IIHF or NHL when two events happen at the same stoppage of play?

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey

How are stats recorded in IIHF or NHL when two events happen at the same stoppage of play?

For example, team A receives 2-minute penalty at time 12:05. The game is stopped and after the face-off team B manages to shoot a goal under 1 second from face-off at time 12:05 too.

Another example is, team A scores a goal at time 15:20. Player from team B is frustrated and hits an opponent after what he receives 5-minute penalty and game misconduct, but this happened when the time was stopped at 15:20 after the goal was scored.

In both examples, a penalty and goal happened at the same time, but not in the same order. It results in a power-play goal and penalty termination in the first example, and a goal and major penalty advantage in the second example - totally different things.

Are these records manually checked by officials to be correct?
Because on NHL game-record sheet are written only minutes and seconds as 15:20, not milliseconds as 15:20,016 (still, in the second example, the time will be exactly the same). It is easy to record this live one by one, but what about writing all records independently and processing them later? How is the correct order determined?

Comment: What kind of answer would answer your question, beyond "in the order they occur"?  I'd also suggest that "are they checked" is probably a separate question - it's a very different thing, as in particular I'm sure they don't check *just this specific thing*.

Comment: I figured it out meanwhile. In NHL stats API they have it ordered with a number how they occurred in the match. However, there is still need for checking the end of penalties. If goal scored at the time a penalty ended was a power-play goal or even-strength goal. In NHL they add a flag to the goal event like PP/SH/EV goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NHL database every event has an order in match number. If events happen at the end of a penalty which lasted for the time it normally should without terminating it with a goal, these events have a flag if they happened in a power-play, short-handed play or at even strength (these flags are on all goal events).